# How to retrieve disabled Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

I want to retrieve my Gmail account. I used it 2 year before, 2 year before some security problem happened suddenly Gmail account blocked, I can't use Gmail account up-to now.

I tried to create same username, account creation not accepting, its showing username already exits. Actually I want that username,even data is deleted also no problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Google disabled some account temporarily. In majority of cases, when an account is compromised for some security reasons, Google takes this action. You are not required to over react in this type of situation. All you need to do is to follow their instructions. After due verification, your account will be restored within a stipulated time.

If you are redirected from sign-in page to a page showing message that your Google account is disabled, then getting your account back may be little bit problematic. There is no guarantee that you are going to get back your account. The first step should obviously be to contact them. You are required to write a message that you have already gone through all Terms and Services along with Privacy Policies. And, you are going to follow all of these terms strictly. You need to also ask them the specific reason behind Google’s decision to disable your account. Now, you need to wait for 48 hours. If you don’t get any response, you are required to again resubmit the form.

Otherwise visit `Gmail Help Forum` and start a new thread asking for help.

Here is some useful links :

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/32046?hl=en

http://gmailaccountrecovery.blogspot.in/

Comment: If you are affiliated with the blog, please disclose that in your answer.

Comment: No, I am not affiliated with the blog.